# Php script won't download my epub

Tags: php, epub, epub3

I run 2 scripts, one after the other, the first one creates the ebook and stores it on the server, the second one downloads it and deletes all the files that were used to create the ebook. The scripts work perfectly, except for the download part, its not downloading the book :(

Here is the download script:

```
$file = "../FYP/eBook.epub";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    readfile($file);
    echo "file does exist";
unlink($file);
}
```

As you can see, ive commented out the header, because it doesnt work, i even tried 'application/octet-stream'and 'application/epub+zip' but no success.

And here is what is being outputted on the console log:

```
PK�X�F���Ҭ�OEBPS/title.xhtmlM���0�w��Zb(J����u���D�E���? �����le%xX���F+�D�<W��z����ih�2hN�r�ob��ĳ  ��@�mQt�G���    R"k^���{�Y��l��&��j���F�:�x������(Fȩ�x�ș.u������q E��N; +u}�|PK�X�F"���*OEBPS/characters.xhtmlm�1�0E���[�
u�,=I.A
Ŗ��7��:t��~���^��&n��k�eY��Q��cYU�;��
@{��r�A���ɶB�5��y
���fj��*�2+HŲbO$
|��oS*�����v�K��,u��G1ͳ��
���6�Q�Ew׸��;��1�i��E;{�ǂS�m��PK�X�Fv�(��4OEBPS/scene155.xhtmlm���� D��
߸�j����'����J���*�����y4#��g��S��7�m����_�/�0��n��ȳqMT)A"��K�����<*�]Ж�`�8�"G���E�_���ӟgx6ໂ����U�-'��T5e�є��ff�S���Yw��d�肉��S9�l�۶ެ5�Lp�;�>�(ṥ��'�/PK�X�F�"�=�YOEBPS/scene156.xhtml�����0D�|�o�am�D��\�jH��
��&TU{�m4��Y;Y����+'��9�6��>���u�5�L�٩�"e&s��O���r���.8�� �*����(p�n�N{��l�W��t�.�o���4��lS���I��D(�d��4���X���Dt
v{٣��P~�k)���V�K���4��'�����,�2�PK�X�F�����OEBPS/scene161.xhtmlM��
�0��>En�v=�Ծ�>�?Y+[��@���U��@>�f����>�Et��Ec,cU��H���i���q�ꤞme��K���=7��+�"�E����m��W��Fg��[�������Ԕ��}+����h�M��6[:�����PK�X�FYl�,�|OEBPS/scene163.xhtml�PAn� ��+|��e������$qCT�"�}M�U�[O���h��-~͝pD��T)E��iRM۶j�a.ڡ+`H3y4�V'8I?��@{�Nn���$��ȴ{�����y�ԑ����n�k��@p�Fï�ypE�\�:��m�����0}�0:G�>���$Lzx�u��3PX^����g�����x�R���d'<���Sl��ꪼhu�ĵ���PK�X�FF��5��OEBPS/scene310.xhtmlM�A
�0E�=���s�]Y�@���85Ҩ��޾�R�j���C^��fi�W�wĔR�nղxm���{ �]_ ���ք'�a���5ʛ�1�rh��X<��+������X����~��k�t<3�����N�Ի��}8��(و�Bx�-o�/PKtu�Foa�,mimetypeK,(��LN,����O-(MҮ�,PKtu�F�o��META-INF/container.xmlU��� D��
�մ��@ML<k��t�D` P�/֤�{�ݙ7��/��S�4�u[��e(���Ū8dͧ$A�Y��e1�"����19���}���DTF�0��Ս��sm�r��t<�/�k����ș��B[�5��5Pj-Ax����n���\�p%�X���PK^�FG(��1�OEBPS/stylesheet.css}�Mn� ���r��t�M�β�����؞��6�ջ��8JkV���<�n`/GM�o�6��j��׆=(�ؐ?rh���ޓ6 
Aa�{�WXu�Zt5�LS%9<^�~�us����օ�m���������{�긃���szT�H���r8d�E�#ln��,������{X`���v���za��!鳈n�ù8�t�;T�M=S�&�^Xc4���nt1�t�&<Q4�G[�Hu�֡�
�z����K���Z���'���O��   �O���S��̗1�+(Fm��BX�F
�)����PK�X�F���OEBPS/content.opf��͎�0����V.>T��4�*V=���x�!�l��&y�^��Vᔙ��o>�����g3��3��*���d��"��_�IZK�!7�Hm}Ʒ��Z��n]�k6b>��W|�N����jȩۦz��P�E/�8�y�5[����)4w��h>v;�n��
Pj�2'@��
��WV��#�KyH���E����I#1���^0VfF������5z��?�!qTsKi7-�+�y���:M�2����+G�p��E��vd*�r&h<1ΗVҚ<�aW�A�BwV�9�6Pd���Y�62�CMEd]�FI���}������pqI���Y����Iy�ׅ���|"w��$���t�s_��?<J�[������G�y�[�H�t9G����e����&#���ٛ��]��˯,�&q~A\=M\�W����ԫ��������D1| d��X`�=dS:�i�Y��T�+2
�9e%�dC"77DÝP�"xz�D�����Žp����E�7������PK�X�F��;��
OEBPS/toc.ncx���n�0��y
�ʫ`.�f"C5�tQ��Dj���c�   �CC��5���)R����?�w.2����ȼ�R�c�01���"R��<��`@�����R�B˧��S�������V���6Mwhr7����!@6!d���E��H�
yu~�=R��0�G0�]똚O~1�������P24<4���b��������T�T���դ�[�vF.&�k�� �褲�.B
,^������3�٥HXUߟ��Z��
(9fBE�W��dA�C�Q^�b����kT痩b/Xv�]��   �EV/tњ�\�\���?����Sk��S�=k�w���|�CB�ȹ�y�r�A7̨BH�SQȑ�?�v�>@v"�_�u�wF�a��,��ux�Rɶ��*��r��tЍZt��t����k���ۗ��
�gu�]�Z�^�9�������ͷΑ�\۩q�n��s�Xf�N��E�G=xPK]�yF�?�!��7OEBPS/Images/51.png��_hE�'Imch�% �R7>����^�6�M���6gܘ�6����N���;��$w|�
��R|�I��/>��/��b�*DB���/�
},Tg.�("���fY��o�~�����ٝ=;7�������쌖��_8�c/-950`Pq�Lϓ<^$%�G i�����rȰ*o�@���h�ɼ��bb'l0�p��;&�ʞa�h�vU�ޥ+�-U8�#��F��̺����s�h&,a�e8YVh",;+n��U�V�B�Y�(�� )��v���9��>���hȌH����˲��F�����bJ\V�cp�hk������N[TS�eB<EK�R�4���(%   VG4�����r��z

L����]�tc�U�Cp��j�`�M�ab��D)�a���6u�]����⣭�B�Cbx�7i�G�)i��W�^�[��؃�����i���x��u%��pM��T���m�R�br&=��'%i:����L,�L��屴���6W��:k����,�i��k���؁�A+v��H����Z��mȊ�3��B]/���nw�*���\��>M��^����DVK�[w�������#�w������ە�\>@gN����f3���Q&zN��W�g�>�������!��z?;H�'N|�CE�{{��0��̷�y>������������MVv�����{m^dvW��[>�9�ˮ�d��
ϲ6����0_�̮|��ط8����������O�:��׾�'q�V��gQ����?
��0����
a䳑���%��?����Ǟ�w�����0թKk+�lDΥ�����?�OR�����m���zw�������??����ʓ����!q�C��8�!q�C��8�!�:t�v?�+Vϩ� �AͲ��7�+��̀���&sv5������p��3��p�+\i��|����o�(�����վL�~�/PK�X�F���Ҭ�OEBPS/title.xhtmlPK�X�F"���*�OEBPS/characters.xhtmlPK�X�Fv�(��4�OEBPS/scene155.xhtmlPK�X�F�"�=�Y�OEBPS/scene156.xhtmlPK�X�F������OEBPS/scene161.xhtmlPK�X�FYl�,�|zOEBPS/scene163.xhtmlPK�X�FF��5���OEBPS/scene310.xhtmlPKtu�Foa�,VmimetypePKtu�F�o���META-INF/container.xmlPK^�FG(��1�iOEBPS/stylesheet.cssPK�X�F����OEBPS/content.opfPK�X�F��;��
�
OEBPS/toc.ncxPK]�yF�?�!��7�OEBPS/Images/51.pngPK

D�file does exist
```

Here is the html/jquery code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            retrievePlays();      
        })

        function retrievePlays(){
            $.post("getPlays.php",{
                'uID' : <?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?>,
            },function(result){
                for (i =0;i<result.length;i++) {
                 $('<tr/>').attr({'id':'play'+result[i].playid}).appendTo("#myPlays");
                 $('<td/>').html(i+1).appendTo("#play" +result[i].playid);
                 $('<td/>').html(result[i].name).appendTo("#play" +result[i].playid);
                 var app= '<td><button class="edit btn btn-warning" onclick=editPlay(this);>Edit</button></td><td></form><button class="edit btn btn-primary" onclick=downloadPlay(this);>Download</button><td><button class="erase btn btn-danger" onclick=deletePlay(this);>Delete</button></td>';
                 $('#play' +result[i].playid).append(app);
                }
                },"json");
        }

      function editPlay(sender){
        var tr = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
        var idstring = tr.getAttribute('id');
        var id = idstring.substr(4,idstring.length);
        console.log(id);
        location.href = "playwrite.php?playID=" + id;
        }

        function deletePlay(sender) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this play?')) {
        var tr = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
        var idstring = tr.getAttribute('id');
        var id = idstring.substr(4,idstring.length);
        console.log(id);

        $.post("deletePlay.php",{
            'pID' : id,
        },function(){
            $('#play'+id).remove();
        });
        } 
        }

        function downloadPlay(sender) {
            var tr = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
        var idstring = tr.getAttribute('id');
        var id = idstring.substr(4,idstring.length);

      $.post("filetest.php",{
            'pID' : id,},
            function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $.post("deleteFiles.php",{'pID' : id,},function(){});
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="main.php">Homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="playwrite.php">New Play</a></li>
      <li class="Logout"><a href="Login.html">Log Out(<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>)</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="mainbox">
        <input id="search_input" placeholder="Type to filter">
        <table id="myPlays" border="1" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <th>Number</th>
            <th id="pnames">Play Name</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Download</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your using header, which tells me you are attempting to send it through a users browser. Do you have a reason why you aren't just linking to the file?

Comment: to record/filter unwanted access maybe? there are countless reasons to download a file through a php script rather through a direct link

Comment: I have no idea what headers are for, just seen them on the documentation

Comment: Why did you use `echo` within a download? Also, what do you mean by "its not downloading the book"? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this snippet to download pdf or doc files in my server.

```
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        break;
        default;
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
```

Comment: just tried it, still  not downloading and doing the same thing on the console. Tried it on a different browser, still not working :/ Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of causes for this, some of them may be very hard to find.

First, your `header` function may be failing.

**Possible solution 1:**

This can be because of newlines **after** the closing tag.

Instead of:

```
<?php include 'my_file.php'; ?>
```

Try:

```
<?php include 'my_file.php';
```

**Possible solution 2:**

Your file may be being saved in UTF8.

This won't show on the screen, but it will send 3 aditional bytes.

Try saving in ASCII, UTF7, UTF8 (without B.O.M), ANSI, windows-1252, ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15.

**Possible solution 3:**

You are doing `echo 'File does exist';`.

And you don't specify a correct mime-type.

Use the mime-type `application/epub+zip` ([source: wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB))

And remove that line.

**Possible solution 4:**

You may be outputting something else.

Try using this:

```
ob_start(); //stops the output from being sent
[write your code]

ob_end_clean();//discards the output

include 'your_script.php';
```

This will capture and discard any output from the file that includes the one that sends the new file to download.

---

Now, lets move to the newly added Javascript.

You are sending a POST to the file using jQuery, then you do something with the file.

Instead of that, set a link like this:

```
<a href="/file_to_download_epub.php?id=<id>" download="epub_file.epub" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

The [`download` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute will force the file to download.

Opening it in a new tab (with the `target="_blank"`) will ensure the file will be in a new tab, in case the `download` attribute isn't supported.

If a user has a plugin/add-on to view epub files, it will display in the browser using this method.

On your PHP, you have to put these lines:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/epub+zip');//important!
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.epub');//also important
```

You had it almost right! This will tell the browser to start a download.

Skip all that Javascript, use a plain `<a>` attribute and you have everything done for yourself.

Comment: Hmmm I tried and it doesnt work! The thing is when I go on the content of the server, and i click straight on filtest.php the download works, but on the webApp it doesnt work on click of the button. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @Zehuntar Can you show a little bit more of code? This is the most generic that I can get. And this always worked for me. Yes, I follow these generic sefl-thaugh steps to solve the same issue you have. And they worked flawlessly to me.

Comment: I've added the jquery code at the top post, I think the problem has to do with the downloadPlay() function, have a look at retrievePlay and downloadPlay and lemme know if theres anything unusual. Thanks!

Comment: @Zehuntar I didn't had time a while ago, but I have now. I've edited the answer. If this doesn't work for you, please say it. I'm here to help you, but I need your help to help you.

Comment: Hey Ismael,thanks for taking the time to answer! We're nearly there! The download is working, but for some weird reason i dont think the parameter is being passed because the eBook is empty, whereas with the POST method the play isn't empty : here is what ive done to it:         `var tester = '<a href="filetest.php?pID='+result[i].playid+'" download="eBook.epub" target="_blank">Download</a>';     $('#play' +result[i].playid).append(app);
                 $('#play' +result[i].playid).append(tester);`

Comment: @Zehuntar Try `$('#play' +result[i].playid).append(app); $('#play' +result[i].playid).append('<a href="filetest.php?pID='+result[i].playid+'" download="eBook.epub" target="_blank" onclick="alert(this.href)">Download</a>');` and check what url is being passed. If everything is alright, try downloading the file and open it in notepad++. If it is empty, try checking if the file is empty before being sent.

Answer (score -2):

ce que tu peux faire...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

/*jquery : the pseudo class triggers the execution of php via ajax */

    $(".epub").mousedown(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "telechargement.php",
            cache: false
          });

    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
/* an html link with a css pseudo class to manage jquery ajax */

<a class="epub" href="https://.../mondoc.epub" target="_blank">
              <h2 class="post-title">
               téléchargez le ebook
              </h2>
            </a>
```

/* the php which allows to increment a counter and redirect to the epub file */

```
<?php 
      include("bdincremente.php"); 
      incrementer_telechargements(); 
      $fichier= "mondoc.epub"; 
      $file = $chemin."/mondoc.epub"; 
      if (file_exists($file)) { 
      header('Location: https://....../mondoc.epub'); exit; } else { echo "pas de fichier..."; } 
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: code php 

<?php

include("bdincremente.php");

incrementer_telechargements();

$morceau = "pdgl.epub";
$file = "epub/pdgl.epub";


   if (file_exists($file)) {

                header('Location: https://....../mondoc.epub');
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "pas de fichier...";
            }




?>

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your answer by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: Please translate all comments to english, as this is the main language on StackOverflow